# Looker Studio - Can't the graph series be set to a value greater than 20?

Tags: looker-studio

I have a following dataset in google sheets [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qPD6OcXaRBLRs5WJf5uyx-zUhPeKT4zJSo27TM73wKU/edit?usp=sharing)

To create a bar chart, I set date to Dimension, sum to Metric, and name to Breakdown Dimension in the SET UP screen.
[image]

Since name has 22 series, I tried to set Series in the STYLE screen to 22, but there are only values up to 20.
[image]
[image]

Is this a limitation of Looker Studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [documentation](https://support.google.com/looker-studio/answer/7165560?hl=en&ref_topic=7059081#zippy=%2Cin-this-article):

> At least 1 metric is required. For charts with a single dimension, you
> can have up to 20 metrics. For charts with 2 dimensions, you can have
> 1 metric.

So yes, 20 is your limit in Looker Studio.